# How do I have the first argument of the =MATCH() function be the value of cells?

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice

I am trying to find duplicates in a column in LibreOffice Calc.  I found the =MATCH function, and think that it will help.  It has three arguments: Search Criterion, Lookup Array, and type.  I want the search criterion to be the values of the cells in the lookup array.  How can I do this?

Comment: You don't want to use `MATCH`: it is the wrong function to use for the purpose of finding duplicates.

Comment: Alright.  Could you explain why, and what I should use instead?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this that I found is next to the column to add a column that shows how many of each using countif, and then using another formula, you could even use countif again, to see how many of those are 2’s. This is a formula way to do it, which I found here: https://yodalearning.com/tutorials/find-duplicate-values/

If you are just trying to find duplicates, and don’t need formulas, You can use the Standard Filter option under Data>Filter>Standard Filter

Comment: It seems the link you linked is for Michealsoft XL.  I am using LibreOffice Calc.  Please read the entire question before answering.  Also, you didn't really answer my question.  I was wonder yet there what the is less it be.